# How to define Location and Display language from Windows Control panel

Tags: delphi, locale

[image]

Delphi xe.

For Tab `Administrative` - Unicode lang
use GetSystemDefaultLangID

For Tab `Formats` -
use GetUserDefaultLangID

**But what do I use for For Tab `Location`?**

For Tab "Keyboard and Language"
for Vista and above: Getlocaleinfo with key LOCALE_CUSTOM_UI_DEFAULT

```
Function GetLocaleInformation(flag: integer): string;
var
  pclca: array[0..20] of char;
begin
  if (GetLocaleInfo(
      //locale_system_default - Always identical values returns
      LOCALE_CUSTOM_UI_DEFAULT // work only Vista-Win7, not Xp **
      ,flag,pclca,19) <= 0 ) then begin
    pclca[0] := #0;
  end;
  Result := pclca;
end;
```

1. How do I define Location in Xp+Win7 and Display Language in Xp?
2. Can be a universal key for definition "Display Language" both for Xp and for Win7
3. How to receive the list of the established languages of the interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***1.1 - How to get selected geographical location (geographic ID) ?***

Use the [`GetUserGeoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318138%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function which returns the [`geographical location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) currently selected by user.

---

***1.2 - How to get selected display language for Multilingual User Interface (MUI) in Windows XP ?***

Use the [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which returns the [`language identifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318691%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) currently selected by user.

---

***2 - Is there an universal way how to get the selected display language supported since Windows XP till Windows 7 ?***

Yes, it is. It's just the previously mentioned [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. There's a remark:

> If the user UI language is part of a Language Interface Pack (LIP) and
>   corresponds to a supplemental locale, this function returns
>   LOCALE_CUSTOM_UI_DEFAULT.

It is supported since Windows 2000 and it should return selected display language even for Windows Vista above ([`LOCALE_CUSTOM_UI_DEFAULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

---

***3 - How to get the list of available user interface languages ?***

Use the [`EnumUILanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317834%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. In Windows XP, it passes the [`language identifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318691%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to the [`EnumUILanguagesProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317835%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) callback function. Since Windows Vista you can even specify additional flags which supplies to pass the language names to that callback function or you can specify the filtering for licensed languages or for the languages allowed by the group policy.